# How to infer function return type and arguments names and types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to create a hook in react native, and in it's params i want to pass a function and it's variables, EX:

```
const useHook = (functionName, functionArgs) {...}
```

and my question is: how can i infer the 'functionName' args types and it's return type too.

so that when i write useHook and i pass a function, intelesense will automatically show me the function args names and types ?

i tryed this but didn't work:

```
const useHook = <T, R>(fun: (args: T) => R, args: T) => {
  fun(args);
}
```

Comment: The code `(functionName, functionArgs) {...}` isn't valid syntax (should there be a `=>` in there maybe?)  And what specifically doesn't work about what you tried?  Do you need multiple arguments or something like [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBArhApgCRCA1jAvDAPAFRkQA8pEwATCGAQzAE8BtAXQBoYAlAPgAoAzOGABcMHgDoJNAE4BzCCPwBKbF07sJY6XIXKsqgN4AoGDCmIocKWBgCw4ybIiKA3IYC+h28CgBLcDbQeYhFoKR8wGXZ6ETA4AFsAI0QpZSMTEzMLKxhiMQAbchkoAAtsLBx6Vw9QSFhM7HgkVAx+NHYAIhp29gBGFxgAegGYBLQCuiA)?  A [mcve] would be very helpful here.

Comment: Thank you @jcalz for your example, it works nice, but what i want is, instead of passing params seperated by comma, i want to pass an object :

i added this:

const useHook = <T extends any[], R>(fun: (...args: T) => R, {...args}: T) => {
  return fun(...args);
}

but the autocompletion detect only args types and not the names of params.

Answer (score 1):

Your function signature is good enough, you just forgot to return the result :

```
const useHook = <T, R>(fun: (args: T) => R, args: T) => {
  return fun(args);
}
```

Or shortend :

```
const useHook = <T, R>(fun: (args: T) => R, args: T) => fun(args);
```